# Как избежать пустую нагрузку на процессор в цикле?

Tags: c++, sfml

Работая над меню игры, которая создаётся с помощью SFML, столкнулся с проблемой "пустой" загрузки процессора в циклах, которые не высчитывают что-либо в прямом значении этого слова, а просто ожидают каких-либо событий от пользователя и меняют состояние (выходят из него или опускаются глубже во внутренние циклы) только тогда, когда что-то происходит, а до тех пор выводят изображение на экран и тому подобное, тем самым нагружая процессор на ~20-30%, хотя реально такие мощности не используются.

Пытался это решить с помощью ожидания события (waitEvent), а не его "вылова" (pollEvent), но это просто стопорило программу. Может быть как-то неправильно этим пользовался.

Да и не только в данном проекте столкнулся с подобным. В других так же, где были аналогичные циклы.

Сам "скелет" подобного цикла выглядит примерно так:

```
while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
            window.close();
    }

    window.clear();
    //window.draw(something);
    window.display();
}
```

---

**Как решать подобные проблемы? Уместно ли будет использовать таймеры или функции типа Sleep()? Какие технологии можно применять для оптимизации подобных ситуаций?**

Comment: Процессор нагружается когда цикл ничего не делает, а попросту гоняет в пустую один и тот же код. Добавьте нагрузку в цикл, тогда процессор не будет нагружен. К примеру, рисуйте в окне. Так же стоит проверять не свернуто ли окно, и если оно свернуто, то тогда делать замедление процесса перерисовки окна, но не функциями вроде `Sleep`.

Comment: @LLENN, он и так рисует в окне, проверяет не было ли окно закрыто и тд.
Искусственно создавать нагрузку? У меня были похожие идеи, но как-то они уж сильно грубыми и неэффективными мне показались

Comment: Не искусственно, а реальную нагрузку, например, обновление фрейма, т.е. передвижение персонажа, расчет угла полета пули, перемещение врагов, и т.д. Т.е. физика, пользовательский ввод и т.д. и т.п. Рисуете вы на видеокарте, она же в свою очередь просто простаивает, вы можете посмотреть на сколько вы ее загружаете. А так же попробуйте использовать вертикальную синхронизацию. [void sf::Window::setVerticalSyncEnabled(bool  enabled)](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#a59041c4556e0351048f8aff366034f61)

Comment: На уровне ассемблера есть команда `hlt` или `pause` в отношении потоков. Это лишь "мысли вслух".

Comment: Таймаут на полинг поставь меньше 1/24 секунды и стопорения не будет.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У класса окна `sf::Window` имеется метод [setFramerateLimit](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.5.1/classsf_1_1Window.php#af4322d315baf93405bf0d5087ad5e784).

Но он не гарантирует тот факт что частота кадров будет равна той, которую вы установили. Т.к. он все так же использует функцию `sf::sleep`.

> Ограничивает частоту кадров до максимальной фиксированной частоты.
>
> Если установлен лимит, окно будет использовать небольшую задержку
>   после каждого вызова `display()`, чтобы гарантировать что текущий кадр
>   длился достаточно долго, и соответствовать пределу частоты кадров.
>   **SFML** будет пытаться соответствовать заданному пределу, насколько это возможно, но так как он внутренне использует `sf::sleep`, точность
>   которого зависит от базовой ОС, результаты могут быть немного
>   неточными (например, вы можете получить 65 кадров в секунду при
>   запросе 60).

Answer (score 1):

Небольшое вступление.

Процессор всегда загружен на 100%, даже если он ничего не делает.
Если в диспетчере написано, что процессор загружен на 1%, это лишь значит, что процессор 99% времени работает в холостую, ожидая полезную нагрузку.

У разных процессоров есть различные механизмы торможения. Одни процессоры могут полностью уснуть, ожидая прерывания на каком-нибудь порте, другие - предоставляют специализированные команды, которые понижают частоту `камня` в тех или иных условиях.

Если вас интересует, как ограничивают скорость работы главного цикла (например, в играх), то там имеется несколько способов. **Каждый со своими клопами.**

В простых случаях для снижения потока пустой информации через процессор можно использовать `Sleep(1);` или что-то аналогичное.

В сложных стратегиях управления работой процессора можно усыплять процесс/поток с последующим пробуждением по событию + срабатыванию таймера ядра ОС.

Важно понимать, что отрисовка и просчеты должны происходить независимо от факта поступления событий, потому что ваше окно может не получать никаких событий несколько секунд, а потом получит 1000 событий за 1 мс.

Часто - и обработка событий, и просчеты, и отрисовка - должны происходить независимо. Иногда для каждого процесса используются сложные алгоритмы планирования и предсказания. Это делается для сглаживания поведения игры на различных устройствах.

Comment: Спасибо! Не подскажите как пользоваться этим флагом? Как он называется в SFML, ведь это же аналог SDL?

Comment: К сожалению, уже не припоминаю, как называется этот флаг в `SDL`. Про `SFML` сказать ничего не могу, никогда не пользовался этой библиотекой.

Answer (score 0):

Решил данную проблему просто заменой внутреннего цикла обработки событий на условный оператор, который ожидает событие и потом его обрабатывает во вложенных операторах:

```
sf::Event event;
if (window.waitEvent(event))
{
   ...
}
```

Получается, что программа на данной строке будет просто ожидать любого события (нажатие клавиши, движение курсора мыши и тд) и дальнейшие итерации основного цикла будут происходить только тогда, когда происходит что-либо, без "пустой" нагрузки на процессор постоянными не контролируемыми итерациями.

По сравнению с предыдущим вариантом, нагрузка снизилась до 1-2% без какой-либо потери функциональности.

Comment: А теперь посмотрите фреймрейт :)

Comment: Нуу, он коррелируется в зависимости от частоты происхождения событий.
Забыл сказать, что это я менюшку реализовывал и в ней особо никаких расчётов проводить не надо. А сама механика игры привязана к времени

Comment: Но всё равно было бы интересно узнать как реализуется оптимизация в геймдеве. Я только начал изучать эту область и хз где искать какие-либо ресурсы по этой тематике

Comment: Есть возможность настроить таймер на посылку событий, чтобы он будил обработчик с частотой желаемого FPS?